# Magento 2.3.1 Base table or view not found

Tags: database, magento2.3, exception

Magento 2.3.1 keep filling logs with these errors:

> system.log

```
[2019-05-04 23:30:12] report.INFO: SELECT `e`.*, `cat_index`.`position` AS `cat_index_position`, `price_index`.`price`, `price_index`.`tax_class_id`, `price_index`.`final_price`, IF(price_index.tier_price IS NOT NULL, LEAST(price_index.min_price, price_index.tier_price), price_index.min_price) AS `minimal_price`, `price_index`.`min_price`, `price_index`.`max_price`, `price_index`.`tier_price` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
 INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index_store0` AS `cat_index` ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id=0 AND cat_index.visibility IN(3, 2, 4) AND cat_index.category_id=0
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.website_id = '0' AND price_index.customer_group_id = 0 WHERE ((`e`.`entity_id` IN(23262))) AND (e.created_in <= '1556754420') AND (e.updated_in > '1556754420') [] []
[2019-05-04 23:30:12] report.ERROR: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'magento231.catalog_category_product_index_store0' doesn't exist, query was: SELECT `e`.*, `cat_index`.`position` AS `cat_index_position`, `price_index`.`price`, `price_index`.`tax_class_id`, `price_index`.`final_price`, IF(price_index.tier_price IS NOT NULL, LEAST(price_index.min_price, price_index.tier_price), price_index.min_price) AS `minimal_price`, `price_index`.`min_price`, `price_index`.`max_price`, `price_index`.`tier_price` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
 INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index_store0` AS `cat_index` ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id=0 AND cat_index.visibility IN(3, 2, 4) AND cat_index.category_id=0
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.website_id = '0' AND price_index.customer_group_id = 0 WHERE ((`e`.`entity_id` IN(23262))) AND (e.created_in <= '1556754420') AND (e.updated_in > '1556754420') [] []
```

system.log is filled with these two errors.

I don't see a problem somewhere or maybe I didn't notice.

I use a two language store. In the times I see in log only crons are running but in their log I don't have issue.All crons successful finished.

Can anyone help me where to check please?

Comment: Hi, Did you resolve this bug ?

Comment: @EvgeniyKapelko No I am sorry

Answer (score 2):

How did you create your database? Did you migrate from another server using mysql dump?

If so the answer is the view part of the question I asked.

[Magento 2.3 introduced a view table which causes issue with import of mysql dump. What's it for?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/274777/magento-2-3-introduced-a-view-table-which-causes-issue-with-import-of-mysql-dump)

think maybe either you are missing the view or the query requiring elevated access in the import interrupted inserting foreign keys into your database

Comment: Yes....it is migrated from magento 1.9.3.8. I checked your post. Is this the fix??

Comment: As how to fix. I think the only thing you can do is install 2.3.1 on separate dev box as fresh install - no migration and try and compare keys to work out what's missing

Comment: Really?? Install new instance? I have 3gb database....what to compare there....So if you dump you can't import again?

Comment: You don't have to start again. I say do a mysql dump on problem install and fresh vanilla install of 2.3.1 and compare foreign keys. See what's missing. Hopefully you can manually add missing to problem install.

Comment: Understood.I will do that and post here! Thank you

Comment: are u sure for this? As I am checking in my database this table **catalog_category_product_index_store0** don't exit at all. I only have **store1** and **store3** because of two language store. I think **store0** is for admin....I am confused

Comment: Yes 0 is admin. The only other thing is are you or an extension doing anything like what is demonstrated in  the following? https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/15187 if so I don't believe there is a solution yet

Comment: Yes. I have an extensions for reports in admin....And I saw that post. This make sense. Because I don't have problems in frontend.