# Magento 2.3 introduced a view table which causes issue with import of mysql dump. What's it for?

Tags: database, magento2.3, sql

If you mysql dump a magento 2.3 store and try to import it elsewhere you get an issue due the the format of the view import query.

The problem part is this:

```
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`PUT_YOUR_DATABASE_USER_NAME_HERE`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY INVOKER VIEW `inventory_stock_1`  AS  select distinct `legacy_stock_status`.`product_id` AS `product_id`,`legacy_stock_status`.`website_id` AS `website_id`,`legacy_stock_status`.`stock_id` AS `stock_id`,`legacy_stock_status`.`qty` AS `quantity`,`legacy_stock_status`.`stock_status` AS `is_salable`,`product`.`sku` AS `sku` from (`cataloginventory_stock_status` `legacy_stock_status` join `catalog_product_entity` `product` on(`legacy_stock_status`.`product_id` = `product`.`entity_id`)) ;
```

You need elevated permissions. The solution is this:

```
CREATE
OR REPLACE
VIEW `inventory_stock_1` AS select
    distinct `legacy_stock_status`.`product_id` AS `product_id`,
    `legacy_stock_status`.`website_id` AS `website_id`,
    `legacy_stock_status`.`stock_id` AS `stock_id`,
    `legacy_stock_status`.`qty` AS `quantity`,
    `legacy_stock_status`.`stock_status` AS `is_salable`,
    `product`.`sku` AS `sku`
from
    ( `cataloginventory_stock_status` `legacy_stock_status`
join `catalog_product_entity` `product` on
        (( `legacy_stock_status`.`product_id` = `product`.`entity_id` )));
```

My question is what is this view table used for? And why a view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's part of the new Magento 2 Multi Source Inventory feature

A view for performance reasons and maintainability. No point in creating yet a other index table that needs to managed when the data is already there but in other tables.

Comment: It's worth highlighting that you have one of these views for each store view. The above example is for store ID 1

Answer (score 1):

You don't need elevate permissions.Try this:

```
wget https://files.magerun.net/n98-magerun2.phar
php n98-magerun2.phar db:dump
```

Done.
Now you can import DB without problems.